# Create empty array of struct gives me an error

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm trying to create an **empty** `array` of a `struct`. Here's my code:

```
struct Item {
    var prop1 : NSDate
    var prop2 : NSDate
}

var myItem = [Item()]
```

But I get an error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'prop1' in call.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Item()` is trying to create an `Item` that is empty, but that's not possible since neither `prop1` nor `prop2` have default values. The [automatically generated initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID87) requires two arguments.

To create an empty array, you can use one of these:

```
var myItem: [Item] = []
var myItem = [Item]()
var myItem = [] as [Item]
```